# How do I change the completion delay in IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

According to the IDLE help, "The AutoCompleteWindow (ACW) will open after a predefined delay (default is two seconds) after a '.' or (in a string) an os.sep is typed."

I would like to change the delay to something other two seconds. I'm unable to find the location of this setting. I've searched for an answer to this and have not found one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a configuration file called `config-extensions.def` buried in the heart of your Python installation that controls this feature, among several others. Fortunately, you don't need to go looking for it, as it seems you can override it. In your home directory (typically `/home/username` on Linux, `/Users/username` on OS X, and `C:\Users\username` on recent versions of Windows), create a directory called `.idlerc` (with a full stop [period] as the first character). In that directory, create a file called `config-extensions.cfg` and add the following content to it:

```ini
[AutoComplete]
enable=1
popupwait=2000
[AutoComplete_cfgBindings]
force-open-completions=<Control-Key-space>
[AutoComplete_bindings]
autocomplete=<Key-Tab>
try-open-completions=<KeyRelease-period> <KeyRelease-slash> <KeyRelease-backslash>
```

Alter the `popupwait=2000` line to whatever you like (`0` for instantaneously, `500` for 1/2 second, etc.), save the file, and completely quit and restart IDLE.

<sup>All of the other stuff up there is from the default `config-extensions.def` file - I'm not sure how much is needed, but it doesn't seem to hurt any to repeat it all.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Later, when I'm more comfortable with python, I think I'll modify configDialog.py and add an entry under the General tab for this setting.

Comment: I am currently reviewing and revising a patch to configDialog.py http://bugs.python.org/issue3068 to add Configure Extensions under Configure Idle on the Options menu.  It will have a tab for each extension, such as autocomplete.  We need it before adding more extensions.

Comment: .idlerc/config-main.cfg only gets entries for options with non-default values. idlelib/config-main.def is read first and then the user overrides. I presume the extension editor will do the same.